# vtable and MSIL

Tags: c#, cil

I have to teach the difference between abstract class and interface. It could help me the answer to the following question. Please help me!!!
Is it possible to see the content of vtable using ILdasm? I would like to see an example that show the difference between vtable in case of an abstract class and an interface in IL language.

Comment: If you are teaching the difference between and interface and an abstract class, teach why you would use one instead of the other, and the purpose of each, not the specific details of how each works. You could tell me how a drill works and how alternating current drives a motor, but that doesn't mean I should wash my clothes with it.

Comment: The way interfaces work in the CLR is possibly more complicated than you anticipate. It's not as simple as just having a pointer to a vtable.

Answer (score 2):

No, the vtable is built at runtime by the CLR class loader.  You can certainly guess at it, it contains pointers to the jitted methods according to the class or interface declaration.

Demonstrating it requires looking at the generated machine code and using the Disassembly and Memory 1 windows.  Be sure to either use the Release build or turn Edit + Continue off when you do, it adds an extra layer of indirection.